# Reading XML file with PHP if date is

Tags: php, xml, date, if-statement

So, I'm trying to create a page that reads the specific XML file on a specific day.
I'm having problem's with this and all the help would be appreciated.

Here's the structure of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<excercises>
  <excercise>
        <name>Test</name>
    <sr></sr>
    <weight>25kg</weight>
    <comment>Testing</comment>
  </excercise>
    <excercise>
    <name>Test II</name>
    <sr></sr>
    <weight>250kg</weight>
    <comment>Testing more</comment>
  </excercise>
</excercises>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php $month = mktime("m"); ?>
<?php $weekday = mktime("weekday"); ?>

<?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 

if ($month == "01","03","05","07","09","11") && ($weekday == "Monday") {
    $doc->loadXML( 'resourceMon.xml' ); }
if ($month == "01","03","05","07","09","11") && ($weekday == "Tuesday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceTue.xml' ); }
if ($month == "01","03","05","07","09","11") && ($weekday == "Thursday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceThu.xml' ); }
if ($month == "01","03","05","07","09","11") && ($weekday == "Friday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceFri.xml' ); }

if ($month == "02","04","06","08","10","12") && ($weekday == "Monday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceMon.xml' ); }
if ($month == "02","04","06","08","10","12") && ($weekday == "Tuesday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceTue.xml' ); }
if ($month == "02","04","06","08","10","12") && ($weekday == "Thursday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceThu.xml' ); }
if ($month == "02","04","06","08","10","12") && ($weekday == "Friday") {
    $doc->load( 'resourceFri.xml' ); }

else { echo "This day is not a right day to workout!"; }


$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);  


$root=$doc->documentElement;

$excercises = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "excercise" ); 
foreach( $excercises as $excercise ) { 
  $names = $excercise->getElementsByTagName( "name" ); 
  $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  $sr = $excercise->getElementsByTagName( "sr" ); 
  $sr = $sr->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  $weights= $excercise->getElementsByTagName( "weight" ); 
  $weight= $weights->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  $comments = $excercise->getElementsByTagName( "comment" ); 
  $comment = $comments->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  echo "<tr><td><b>$name</b></td><td>$sr</td><td>$weight</td><td><i>$comment</i></td></tr>"; 

  } 
?>
```

---

Comment: So what is the problem you're having, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, read the documentation for [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime). It does not work at all like how you're trying to use it.

Secondly, `$foo == "01", "02", ...` is nonsense. Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) if you need such comparison.

Third, you're way overcomplicating things. Do something like:

```
$file = 'resource' . date('D') . '.xml';

$doc->loadXML($file);
```

or

```
switch (date('N')) {
    case 1 :
        $file = 'resourceMon.xml';
        break;
    case 2 :
        ...
    default :
        return false;
}

$doc->loadXML($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write condition like this

```
if (($month == "01" || $month =="03" || $month =="05" || $month =="07" || $month =="09" || $month =="11")) && ($weekday == "Monday") {
    $doc->loadXML( 'resourceMon.xml' ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

[mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) returns a unix timestamp

You need to use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
date('l') // returns Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.
date('m') // returns month in two digits, 01, 02, 03 etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use date() instead of mktime.
2) Use load() instead of loadXML.
3) make an array and find the particular month in the array using in_array()

```
<?php $month = date("m"); 
$weekday = date("D"); 

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 

$monthHaystack = array("01","03","05","07","09","11");
if (in_array($month,$monthHaystack) && ($weekday == "Mon")) {
    $doc->load( 'resourceMon.xml' ); }

else { echo "This day is not a right day to workout!"; }

?>
```

Then the rest stays the same, no xpath needed either.